# Real-time SSH output with Net_SSH (phpseclib)

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I use Net_SSH (phpseclib) to execute SSH commands on an external server. I simply cannot figure out how to have real-time output from the command. I know how to make it run in the background so it's not dependant on the Apache process, but it's unclear how I'd go about showing the external output in real-time instead of having to wait for the command to finish.

My current code is as simple as `$ssh->exec('command')`.

The PHP version used is:

```
[admin@ ~]$ php -v
PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2017 11:31:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant source code. It would also be helpful to know what command you're running on the remote system and whether you could alter that program.

Comment: There is no relevant code to show, and the commands differ.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with libssh2 and output buffering, see example below:

```
$session = ssh2_connect("server.local", 22, array('hostkey'=> 'ssh-rsa' )) or die("Couldn't connect to the SSH Server.");

ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($session, "root", "/path/to/public/key.pub", "/path/to/private/key") or die("couldn't authenticate to server"); // Authenticating to the server with a ssh-key for security purposes

while (ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = ssh2_exec($session, "ping -c 40 google.nl");

echo '<pre class="scroll">';
echo "[root@server ~]# ping -c 5 google.nl\n"; // Command you will execute
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096); // Read the output from the command
    @ flush(); // Flushes the whole php buffer so we can output new data
}
echo "\nDone";
echo '</pre>';
```

Don't forget that you need php 5.6 or lower for ssh2, you can replace the command in the variable $proc by `$ssh->exec('command')` as you use it.

Comment: Oh. If your external command takes a while set your `max_execution_time` in the php.ini to a higher value e.g. 600 (10 minutes).

Comment: The question is about phpseclib, not libssh2. But I do appreciate the answer so will upvote.

Comment: You can modify this as much as needed. As long as the while part stays the same it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it working using this:

```
$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', function($output) {
    echo $output;
});
```

To eliminate the variability in how your system is configured versus mine I'll use Vagrant to establish a common configuration. To that end, here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
end
```

My full phpseclib code (using 1.0.7):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('127.0.0.1', 2222);
$ssh->login('vagrant', 'vagrant');

$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', function($output) {
    echo $output;
});
```

A youtube video of the output:

https://youtu.be/j9-q3024eEk

If it's not working then several possibilities exist.

1. Maybe the "command" you're running simply doesn't dump output real time. Or maybe it requires a PTY or something. It's hard to comment since you haven't said what the command you're trying to run is. As my post demonstrates there *are* commands that my solution *does* work with.
2. Maybe it works with Vagrant but not with your system. Maybe your system has been configured in some funky way or something. In this scenario I guess what'd help is if you provided the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` and then `echo $ssh->getLog();`. Post the results in pastebin.com and then post the link.

edit: if you're running this in a webserver vs in the CLI you may encounter issues with how the webserver is setup - issues that go past phpseclib. For example, does this output real time or does it lock up?:

```
while (true) {
    echo "test\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

`flush()` / `ob_flush()` might help but ultimately this would depend on the webserver you're using (Apache, nginx, etc), the SAPI you're using (CGI, Apache module, etc), etc.

I would consider this to be a "funky configuration".

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards - well it works for me with the command that I tried it out with. I have copiously edited my answer to document this fact. Maybe whatever command you're using works differently. Or maybe your system has some screwed up configuration settings or something. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: Any command (be it `ping` or `yum update`) fail. I highly doubt my system has 'screwed' something up, I think rather something needs to be altered in the default PHP configuration.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards - are you trying to do it in a webserver / browser? My example was in the CLI. Does `while (true) { echo "test\n"; sleep(1); }` output stuff real time? If not then some combination of `flush();` or `ob_flush();` but otherwise I'm thinking that a new SO question might be appropriate since the problem really has nothing to do with phpseclib and focusing on phpseclib could in fact be a distraction and depriving you of answers from other people who might be better qualified to help you.

Comment: Like if you're trying to do it in a webserver / browser the webserver you're using (Apache, Nginx, etc) could have an impact, the PHP SAPI you're using (CGI, Apache module, etc), etc

Comment: Yes, I'm using this in a web server.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards - does `while (true) { echo "test\n"; sleep(1); }` give you real time output?